# Read line from text and submit information?

Tags: vb.net, click, notepad

I was wondering if it was possible to have a *.txt* file with a bunch of words such as:

```
Gaming  
Programs  
Home  
Select
```

and have these words run one by one through the value on here:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If Not number_of_ticks > NumericUpDown1.Value Then
        number_of_ticks += 1
        If ((WebBrowser1.IsBusy)) Then
        Else
            If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString = "https://live.xbox.com/en-US/ChangeGamertag" Then


                WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("NewGamertag").SetAttribute("value", txtTurbo.Text)

                WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("claimIt").InvokeMember("Click")
            Else

                WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://live.xbox.com/en-US/ChangeGamertag")

            End If
        End If

    Else
        'number_of_ticks has exceed the maximum amount of allowed ticks
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        WebBrowser1.Refresh()

        number_of_ticks = 0
        Timer1.Enabled = True

    End If

End Sub
```

So the first line would have a value of "Gaming" in this, rather then going by the value of the textbox (txtTurbo.text)

```
   WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("NewGamertag").SetAttribute("value", txtTurbo.Text)
```

And then after submitting through this:

```
   WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://live.xbox.com/en-US/ChangeGamertag")
```

change the value to "Programs", and so on and so on until it reaches the end of all the lines on the *.txt* file. How would I go about this as I have never worked with reading a *.txt* file from Visual Basic.

Comment: Is this a client-side scripting?

Comment: Your code are so confuse to read

Answer (score 0):

To read a text file, you will need this code

```
 Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim line As String

        ' Create new StreamReader instance.
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("c:\\temp\cid.txt")
        ' Read one line from file
        line = reader.ReadLine
        ' Write the line we read from "cid.txt"
        MessageBox.Show(line)
    End Sub
End Class
```

But, for reading line by line i must try again, cause your code are confuse to read.

**UPDATE**

Cause your question not clear, so maybe i guess like this

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "path.txt"

Dim TextLine As String

If System.IO.File.Exists( path ) = True Then

Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(path)

Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1

TextLine = TextLine & objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine

Loop

txtturbo.Text = TextLine

Else

MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")

End If
```

change below to you want

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://live.xbox.com/en-US/" & txtturbo.text)
```